# Ubuntu on virtual box

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, virtualbox, system

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on virtual box 6.1.30 on my mac OS Monterey.

I successfully created a Virtual Machine and When I click on start, the installation process does not display, only the black screen is displaying and nothing else..

On Searching Google and Other, I found changing display setting may help, then I tried changing the Display -> Graphics Controller -> VMSVGA (in virtual box settings) but no success, I am not able to change to other Display settings, it says -> Invalid Settings.

I tried increasing Video Memory to 64 MB, but no success

Pl help me to identify the error and rectify it to install the Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtualbox.

**Disk File Checking was happening successfully**

[image]

**Processing Ubuntu**

[image]

**--> Here comes the black <---** and nothing happens even after waiting for long.

[image]
Thanks you

Comment: Which Mac are you using to run VirtualBox? Does it use an Intel or M1 CPU?

Comment: Intel Processors

Comment: Did you configured virtualbox to meet [minimal requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it several times. but anyhow I managed to install Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox successfully and upgraded it. but not Ubuntu 20.04 directly ..